# Crop polygon image using opencvsharp in unity?

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am passing four coordinates such that the cropped part is not rectangle or square, So I can not use getpixels() in unity.

Can anyone tell me how to crop an image by passing four coordinates in unity.

Or by using opencvsharp in unity to crop an image by passing four coordinates.

Thanks in advance.